# SQL DML insert trigger

Tags: sql-server

trying to create a dml trigger that checks if column data is present before inserting new data on a different table. Here's what I have so far

```
CREATE TRIGGER filter2 ON Sales.CustReviews
AFTER INSERT
AS
IF EXISTS (SELECT *
           FROM Sales.Orders AS so
           JOIN sales.CustReviews AS cr ON so.custid = cr.custid
           WHERE  so.Ordershipped = 'no'
          )  

BEGIN
RAISERROR ('Need to place order before posting review', 16, 1);
ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;
RETURN

END;
```

GO

---

```
INSERT INTO Sales.CustReviews (custid, comment) VALUES ('2', 'this product sucks')
```

I want the above code to fail, because it does not have an order shipped because default is set to 'no' (there is only 1 order in sales.order and the custid is 1)

Comment: So is it mysql, or sql-server? There are subtle differences. Please remove the tag that does not apply.

Comment: you should instead raise an error if there is no shipped order with the requested `custid`

Comment: why not use foreign key contraints ?

Comment: So a customer can post a review on **anything** so long as that customer is associated with at least one order? Does that sound correct? And that review is not associated with any particular product/service/item? Not associated with any particular order? Not associated with anything that the customer has, in fact, ordered? If the customer has more than one order, s/he still cannot post comments if any order has not been shipped? This sounds like a doomed system.

Comment: @SMor that is correct, originally I had it filter by orderid, not by if the order was shipped or not. I was just playing around with the trigger trying to get it to work.

Comment: @invrt - what is currently not working in your trigger? (rollaback transaction is not really necessary but I don't think that this is your problem)

Comment: I would expect to see some reference to the inserted table. Have you seen the example Using a DML AFTER trigger to enforce a business rule between the PurchaseOrderHeader and Vendor tables in the docs https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-trigger-transact-sql.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER filter2 ON Sales.CustReviews
AFTER INSERT
AS
BEGIN
    IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
               FROM Sales.Orders AS so
               JOIN sales.CustReviews AS cr ON so.custid = cr.custid
               WHERE so.Ordershipped <> 'no'
              )
        THROW 60000, 'Error Message!', 1;
    RETURN;
END;
GO

BEGIN TRY
    BEGIN TRANSACTION;
    INSERT INTO Sales.CustReviews (custid, comment) VALUES ('2', 'this product sucks');
    COMMIT TRANSACTION;
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0
        ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;
    THROW;
END CATCH;
```